# Can't Find Manifest Defined Receiver ~1% of the Time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have an @AAR that requires an entry in the consuming application's manifest.  During the bootstrapping of my library I inspect the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the required receiver and if I can't find it I throw a `RuntimeException` as my library will not function properly.  This works on 99% of the installations, but there are a small number of installations that throw this `RuntimeException` when the receiver clearly exists.

Android v4.4 - v5.1.1 are all included in the crash reports.  Samsung, Lenovo, Nexus 4, Nexus 5, etc. are all affected devices.

The most interesting clue is that ~75% of the crashes are on rooted devices.  Speculation has been that this is a result of some custom ROM or some other application that is interfering with the receiver's detection.

I have tested with a rooted Nexus 5 w/4.4.4 and it works fine.  I have tested with a stock Nexus 5 w/5.1.1 and it works fine.  I have tested with a Nexus 5 running CyanogenMod 12.1 (latest release) and it works fine.  I applied all the Privacy Guard options available and it still works fine.

Really at a loss and don't want to abandon the affected users.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Activities, etc. removed for brevity -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Class

```
public class CheckSetup {

        // Other methods removed for brevity

    public void checkManifest() {
        List<ResolveInfo> receiversInfo;

        Intent checkIntent = new Intent(applicationContext, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        receiversInfo = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(checkIntent, 0);

        boolean receiverFound = false;

        if (receiversInfo != null) {
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : receiversInfo) {
                if (resolveInfo.activityInfo != null && resolveInfo.activityInfo.name.equals(MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getName()) && resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals(packageName)) {
                    receiverFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!receiverFound) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s definition not found in AndroidManifest.xml", MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've been able to reproduce this behavior is by installing a 3rd party application that allows me to selectively disable `Services` and `Receivers`.  I'm not sure why anyone would want to do this and once disabled there's no way to re-enable them from my AAR.

Best case has been to throw an exception during development and simply output to LogCat for production signed releases.

An example of such an app can be found here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools

Answer (score -1):

Can you remove android:exported="true" and check ? Ideally android:exported should be false.

Comment: Ideally?  The documentation states otherwise http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html and, as noted above, this works on 99.9% of devices on which this code executes.